# Swift: How to feed in certain pic if a button has been pressed? Giant if statement?

Tags: swift

So I have a tic tac toe game and I need help with a big if statement to say basically:

```
If button 1 = pressed then feed this set of imgs into the line of code annotated below, else feed in these imgs
```

And do this for 6 or so different buttons. I just need help with the logistics and I'm a beginner, so please explain all suggestions clearly. Thank you!

My code:

```
func setImgforCircle(spot:Int, player:Int) {
        var playerMark = player == 1 ? "Red_x" : "Red_o" 

if blueBtnClicked(sender: UIButton.self) = highlighted {  //This block does not work
            playerMark = player == 1 ? "Blue_x" : "Blue_o" 
        }

        plays[spot] = player
        switch spot {
        case 1:
            circle1.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 2:
            circle2.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 3:
            circle3.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 4:
            circle4.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 5:
            circle5.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 6:
            circle6.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 7:
            circle7.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 8:
            circle8.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 9:
            circle9.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

        default:
            circle2.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your circles in an array and then you can access the correct circle by spot:

```
var circles = [circle1,circle2,circle3,etc]
circles[spot].image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
```

You should create a naming system for you images. Something like:

```
<player>_<spot>_<type>
```

So an example image name would be

```
1_3_o
```

Then you can programatically create your image name:

```
var imageName = "\(player)_\(spot)_\(type)"
circles[spot].image = UIImage(named: imageName)
```

I don't understand what logic you are trying to use to determine which "type" it is, but I imagine it should be based off of who's turn it is.

Comment: No no that's not the issue. I need to feed in different asset images. So basically if a certain button has been pressed, playerMark needs to be equal to 2 different images instead of "Red_x" and "Red_o"

Comment: ok, I still don't understand what your asking. You need to layout exactly what your different states are for each of the "circles".

Comment: The circles are different UIImageViews with buttons over them. They are the different spots on the tic tac toe board. I need to feed different images into these circles (the image views) depending on if 1 of 6 buttons have been pressed. See the edit I made above ^

Comment: So you have 9 spots and each spot has 4 different images (red x, red o, blue x, blue o) making a total of 36 different images?

Comment: Yeah basically. The red images should be brought into playerMark when red button is clicked, etc

Comment: How do I create a naming system?

Comment: I created one for you. You just have to name your images according to that "system". I am not talking about a "system" in any technical sense, just a list of rules that you can follow when naming the images so that you can generate the names programmatically later.

Comment: Ok sorry I'm new to this. So once I create this naming system how would I feed these now named images into "playerMark" when the actual blue button is clicked or any of the other buttons I have? I can't put an IBAction into a function so..?

Comment: You are thinking of this backwards. Each button must trigger this `setImgforCircle` method. Figure out which button is tapped (you can assign to the buttons `tag` property to differentiate them) and then call this method with a parameter for the `type` you want used..

Comment: Ok..I think I understand. Could you possibly write an example IBAction that would trigger the setImgforCircle function and do what you wrote above? Also how would that work because the actual image should show up when the user clicks one of the spots not when the user clicks the blue button.

Comment: I would prefer you try to write it yourself and when you run into a problem that you can't find the answer to by searching the internet, post here or post a new question. You will learn much better that way and I can dedicate my time on Stack Overflow to questions that help more than just one person.

Comment: Ok I understand but again- how would your suggestion work because the actual image should show up when the user clicks one of the spots not when the user clicks the blue button.

Comment: @user3781199 This is not the right format to discuss this. Stack Overflow is for well framed questions that have relatively succinct and straightforward answers so that they can benefit lots of people. I recommend finding a forum to ask this kind of more open ended question. Also perhaps [reddit's swift subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/swift/) (although this really doesn't have much of anything to do with Swift).